# Drop all emails that aren't forwarded by postfix

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding, email-bounces, mailbox

I'm setting up a forwarding only email server. I want to apply some static forwarding rules to all incoming emails and bounce all other incoming emails (and not store them locally).

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
myhostname = sputnik.*domain*.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = sputnik.*domain*.com, localhost.*domain*.com, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/24 [::1]/128 [fe80::%eth0]/64
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

`/etc/postfix/virtual`

```
domain1.com anything
@domain1.com catchall@domain2.com
mail1@domain1.com person1@domain2.com

domain3.com anything
mail2@domain3.com person2@domain4.com
```

Example outcomes:

- anything@domain1.com -> catchall@domain2.com
- mail1@domain1.com -> person1@domain2.com
- something@domain3.com -> *bounce*
- mail2@domain3.com -> person2@domain4.com
- anything@domain-xyz.com -> *bounce*

Currently instead of bouncing the emails they are getting stored at `/var/mail/*username*` and the sender isn't alerted that the email didn't go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postfix documentation has an example of this under [mail forwarding domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding). I'm not sure what's going on with your `mydestination` line (Postfix doesn't seem to support wildcards here), but you need to list `domain1.com` and `domain3.com` under [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) (and **not** under [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination)). Also make sure that you've run `postmap` on `/etc/postfix/virtual`.

```
virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com, domain3.com
```